# A ring without zero divisors that can't be extended to a ring with division

Tags: ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

In the book that I read it says that A. Malcev gave such an example in 1936.
But I can't find it...
any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for "cannot be embedded in a division ring" with Malcev's name yielded [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-03/S0002-9939-1961-0124355-6/S0002-9939-1961-0124355-6.pdf), which cites the example on the final page.

> Malcev, A. L. "On the immersion of an algebraic ring into a field." Mathematische Annalen 113.1 (1937): 686-691.

Comment: Malcev’s paper is freely available [here](https://eudml.org/doc/159893).